# How to pass additional parameters when using MapToStoredProcedure

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

As you know, we can map the Insert/Update/Delete functionality of EF to custom Stored Procedures on server.

let's suppose I have some code like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Attitude).MapToStoredProcedures(Sub(e)
   e.Insert(Function(f) f.HasName("sp_AttitudeInsert"))
   e.Update(Function(f) f.HasName("sp_AttitudeUpdate"))
   e.Delete(Function(f) f.HasName("sp_AttitudeDelete"))
End Sub)
```

now i want to pass some additional parameters to `sp_AttitudeInsert` or other SPs when EF wants to call them.
how can i do that?

Comment: are you planning to alter the generated store procedure then send the additional parameter from app ?

Comment: Yes exactly!
I'm developing a time-based system with ability to restore to any date and run the application under specific date, so i need to pass some parameters to my SPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Parameter - 1 Property

> Parameter names correspond to the property names. - [Source](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=code%20first%20insert%2Fupdate%2Fdelete%20stored%20procedure%20mapping)

Just Add additional property in your model.

```
public DateTime AdditionalSpecificDate { get; set; }
```

And intercept it during save changes to set the value because you want it on every call `when EF wants to call them`.

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{   
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
       var addedAttitudes = ChangeTracker.Entries<Attitude>()
          .Where(q => q.State == EntityState.Added);
       foreach (var attitude in addedAttitudes)
       {
           attitude.Entity.AdditionalSpecificDate = DateTime.Now;
       }
       return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, why I couldn't solve this simple thing! i was trying to pass a parameter.
thank you very much :)